# What are java equivalents to JS push, concat, unshift?

Tags: java, javascript

I'm trying to convert the following `JS` to `Java`:

```
serializeSig:function(r,s){
var rBa=r.toByteArraySigned();
var sBa=s.toByteArraySigned();
var sequence=[];
sequence.push(2);
sequence.push(rBa.length);
sequence=sequence.concat(rBa);
sequence.push(2);
sequence.push(sBa.length);
sequence=sequence.concat(sBa);
sequence.unshift(sequence.length);
sequence.unshift(48);
return sequence
}
```

I think `push` would translate to `add`, concat to some kind of `addAll`, but what is `unshift`? And of what type would my variables in java be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like you are trying to use a ByteBuffer to serialize some data.

```
 public static void serialize(ByteBuffer bb, String r, String s) {
      bb.put(48);
      int start = bb.position();
      bb.put(0); // padding.
      bb.put(2);
      byte[] rBa = r.getBytes();
      bb.put((byte) rBa.length);
      bb.put(rBa);
      byte[] sBa = s.getBytes();
      bb.put((byte) sBa.length);
      bb.put(sBa);
      bb.put(start, (byte) (bb.position() - start - 1));
}
```

Using an `List<Byte>` is very inefficient and not supported by the packages which do IO.

Answer (score 5):

`myArray.unshift(obj)` corresponds to `myList.add(0, obj)`.

A byte array in Java is `byte[]`.  A list of byte arrays would be a `List<byte[]>`.  (That's `java.util.List`, not `java.awt.List`, just in case you get the wrong import.)

EDIT: Looks like you are trying to create a byte array, not a list of byte arrays.  In that case, you should use a `java.nio.ByteBuffer`, or possibly a `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream`.  The latter has to be written to sequentially -- you cannot do the equivalent of an `unshift`.

Comment: Please see @PeterLawrey's answer.  His is better than mine.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an arraylist of Bytes.

```
List<Byte> sequence = new ArrayList<>();
```

To add to the end of an arraylist use:

```
sequence.add(item);
```

To add to the front use:

```
sequence.add(0, item);
```